# Cannot enter password correctly on Gnome 41.2 in terminal after typing something on number pad

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome, sudo

I don't even know how to properly put it in words. When I accidentally enter my sudo password, when something requests it in the terminal with the number pad, which **is deactivated**, I cannot enter the password correctly again.

So step by step what I do:

1. Running `sudo` in Gnome Terminal in bash. My password is requested.
2. I enter my password, using the number pad of my keyboard.
3. Accidentally I realize that my number pad was deactivated (sometimes I use the primary functions of the numpad to browse documents).
4. I realize my mistake and try to enter my password without the numpad. It is always wrong. Even when I:

   - Using a fresh shell
   - Closing and opening Gnome Terminal

I wonder what is going on? In what state is sudo? ... and how can I use my password again, without logging out and in again?

My environment:

- Gnome 41.2
- Arch Linux (up to date)
- `sg` keyboard layout (de_CH)

Comment: When the problem occurs, does the number pad work normally in plain command line where you can see what you type?

Comment: Yes, after I cancelled the password request, I can type in plain normally. With the numpad and other ways to compose the password.

Comment: Change password to alpha-numeric, so you won't be tempted to use the keypad ;-)